# Create SOAP envelope programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, soap

I have this Java code:

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

QName qualifiedName = new QName("http://mysite.com.br/",
"getQuantidade", "ns2");
SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(qualifiedName);
SOAPElement codigoProduto = element.addChildElement(new QName("codigo"));
codigoProduto.setValue("ARQ");
SOAPElement quantidade = element.addChildElement(new QName("quantidade"));
quantidade.setValue("2");

message.writeTo(System.out);
```

I'd like to do the same thing in C#: mount a SOAP envelope steb by step using classes. I did some research and didn't find anything like this.

What would be the best way to do it?
I don't want the exact code as answer, just point me the way (:

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but the place I would start is the `MessageEncoderFactory` returned by [`TextMessageEncodingBindingElement.CreateMessageEncoderFactory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement.createmessageencoderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx), my next step would be check the `Encoder` object that [`MessageEncoderFactory.Encoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoderfactory.encoder(v=vs.110).aspx) returns for the functionality you are looking for.